# Xcode 4 can't find CPPUNIT

Tags: unit-testing, xcode4, cppunit

I installed Xcode 4 awhile ago and I finally got around to getting cppunit installed. I tried using it in one of my projects last night and I keep getting errors that Xcode cannot find cppunit files.
E.g. `Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'cppunit/extensions/TestFactoryRegistry.h'` not found.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "exception.h"
#include "dataStruct.h"
#include <cppunit/extensions/TestFactoryRegistry.h>
#include <cppunit/ui/text/TestRunner.h>

int main ()
{
    CppUnit::TextUi::TestRunner runner;
    CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry &registry = CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry();

    runner.addTest (registry.makeTest ());

    return runner.run ("", false);
}
```

So I checked /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib and all the cppunit files are there. There were no errors when I installed cppunit either. It is my understanding that Xcode searches /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib by default. Do I need to add something to a path variable or change a project setting to get it to work?

Thanks in Advance,
Madison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. You need to add custom search paths to the project:[image: search paths]

And then you have to tell the linker what to do:[image: linker instructions]